# Visual c# decimal places and currency

Tags: c#, currency, decimal

I'm a novice with C# and I've read a few other questions about decimals but still goes over my head , so I ask how do i 1) Change Average Inventory to english pounds as i have read questions but they all seem to be static ones where as mine are changing.

Average inventory = (Beginning inventory + Ending inventory) / 2.0

Turnover = Cost of goods sold / Average inventory

http://i42.tinypic.com/17bvpv.png

So All im trying to achieve is changing Average Inventory to currency a NO decimal places , possibly rounding. Changing TurnOver to 1 Decimal Place.

These are some codes i found but there meaning is beyond me

```
        //decimal.Round = something.ToString("$#,2") ;
       // Decimal.Round = resultDecimal = decimal.Round(amountDecimal, 2);

       // decimal.Round(DecimalValue, Integer = .1);

        //decimal.Round(1.25M, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);  
       // double after1 = Math.Round(before1, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

       // Math.Round(3.44, 1); //Returns 3.4.
        //decimal.Round(1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal d = 100000.123456M;
var s = d.ToString("C0", new CultureInfo("en-GB")); //gives £100,000
```

Where the `C` indicated currency formatting and the `0` indicated the nr. of decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Magnus , CultureInfo doesnt seem to be recognised but it wants to change it to CultureInfoConverter , but this gives me various errors ;

Error 1 'System.ComponentModel.CultureInfoConverter' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments C:\Users\r2-bothwell\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Q1_10018591\Q1_10018591\Form1.cs 94 39 Q1_10018591

Comment: Error 2 The best overloaded method match for 'decimal.ToString(string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\r2-bothwell\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Q1_10018591\Q1_10018591\Form1.cs 94 21 Q1_10018591

Error 3 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.ComponentModel.CultureInfoConverter' to 'System.IFormatProvider' C:\Users\r2-bothwell\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Q1_10018591\Q1_10018591\Form1.cs 94 39 Q1_10018591

Comment: @Bothwell the `CultureInfo` class is in `System.Globalization`

Comment: No errors but it hasnt changed anything , my numbers change is that what the Var is for to account for Variables ?

        private void average_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Average Inventory text box
            decimal d = 11300.00M;
            var s = d.ToString("C00", new CultureInfo ("en-GB")); //gives £100,000

Comment: @Bothwell you're gonna have to set variable `s` to whatever textbox you want to show it in...

Comment: I changed to to the average textbox but still no change , does "d" or anything else need to be changed , remember i have a complete noob at this heh.

Comment: @Bothwell I'm sorry, but I think you need to read some introduction books to C#.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

decimal d = 100000.123M;
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-GB", false).NumberFormat;
nfi.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 0;
var s = d.ToString("C", nfi);
```

Comment: do you mean to put that at the very top or under the ; private void average_textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

As Iget an error saying ; Error 1 A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods C:\Users\r2-bothwell\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Q1_10018591\Q1_10018591\Form1.cs 10 2 Q1_10018591
when put above the rest of the stuff

Comment: put the _using System.Globalization_ line at the top of your source file - the rest of the code should be inside your TextChanged event handler